# Hive join with huge tables consuming more timr

Tags: hive, hiveql

Table a contains fields customer ID and groupid.the table is very huge and majority of the customer ID falls under 1000 different groups.the joining table also contains the groupid and  role name
basically the join is to get the rolename from this table b based on groupid.let me know how to make the join run faster in hive

Comment: in Java or Python ?

Comment: Want to implement in hive sql

Comment: what is the size of first an second table? Is groupid unique in the second table? Also please provide query and EXPLAIN output

Comment: Size of the left table is 11930830207 and number of rows is 159082822.size of right table is 2306125103 and number of rows is 8976516.in the left table groupid is not unique.many customers can be tagged under 1 groupid.in the right table as well groupid can have multiple roles but one groupid can have a maximum of 19 roles associated

Comment: STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
2   Stage-4 is a root stage , consists of Stage-1
3   Stage-1
4   Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1

Comment: Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: group_member
            Statistics: Num rows: 159082822 Data size: 178809091928 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Reduce Output Operator
key expressions: group_id (type: string)
sort order: +
Map-reduce partition columns: group_id (type: string)
Statistics: Num rows: 159082822 Data size: 178809091928 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
value expressions: member_guid (type: string)

Comment: TableScan
            alias: adminrole
            Statistics: Num rows: 8976516 Data size: 2297148587 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Reduce Output Operator
key expressions: group_id (type: string)
sort order: +
Map-reduce partition columns: group_id (type: string)
Statistics: Num rows: 8976516 Data size: 2297148587 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
value expressions: admin_role (type: string)

Comment: Reduce Operator Tree:
        Join Operator
          condition map:
 Left Outer Join0 to 1
          keys:
            0 group_id (type: string)
            1 group_id (type: string)
          outputColumnNames: _col0, _col19
          Statistics: Num rows: 174991107 Data size: 196690005383 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE

Comment: File Output Operator
  compressed: false
  Statistics: Num rows: 87495553 Data size: 98345002129 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE

Comment: Sorry could not paste the entire explain plan so had to break it up